Why won't this give command with attribute modifiers work?
Why won't this give command with attribute modifiers work?
/give Dynamic_K minecraft:iron_sword[custom_name='["",{"text":"The Whack-Whomp","italic":false}]',attribute_modifiers={modifiers:[{type:"generic.attack_speed",amount:1000000000,operation:add_multiplied_base,id:1731222638456}]},unbreakable={}]

Is the amount of attack damage too high?
I have experimented with lowering it even down to just 10, but something is still wrong, and I cannot figure out what.
/give Dynamic_K minecraft:iron_sword 1 [custom_name='["",{"text":"The Whack-Whomp","italic":false}]',attribute_modifiers={modifiers:[{type:"generic.attack_speed",amount:1000000000,operation:add_value,id:1731222813431}]},unbreakable={}]

Another one of my attempts. This one also doesn't work [I'm playing Java 1.21.3]

Try this:
/give Dynamic_K minecraft:iron_sword{display:{Name:'{"text":"The Whack-Whomp","italic":false}'},Unbreakable:1b,AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attack_speed",Name:"generic.attack_speed",Amount:1000000000,Operation:0,UUID:[I;17312228,13431,0,0]}]} 1
Unbreakable should be 1b from what I can recall and the name was nested incorrectly.

This is a pre-1.20.5 syntax command.
